# How to create a spiral 3d structure?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I want to create a helical/spiral structure like the figure below. I tried to create a circle and poke faces after that I dont know how to extend it in z direction to look like a spiral.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *'screw modifier'* to do that.

Here is two examples, just starting with an edge (segment) a bit rotated and placed differently relatively to the objects origins:

[image]

The modifier starts with a base mesh and extrudes it around an axis (of the mesh itself or the one of another object). The *'screw'* parameter give the elongation along the axis.

[image]